# restricting staff users to user dashboard

Tags: django

I want to restrict staff users from going to normal user dashboard

```
def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
       if user.is_active:
          return redirect('admin')
       esle:
           login(request, user)
           return redirect('users:home')


        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

I wan the staff types to only login from admin panel and they shouldn't be able to access users dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put restrictions in your user dashboard view rather than changing in login view. You can do it like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def dashboard_view(request):
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
       return redirect('admin:index')

    # rest of the logic
```